# ¿Qué identificador de dispositivo podría utilizar en Android?

Tags: android, flutter

Estoy desarrollando una app con flutter, y necesito un identificador único del dispositivo.
Estaba pensando en un token, pero no tengo la menor idea de cómo implementarlo.
Estoy utilizando *device_info_plus* para traer los datos del dispositivo; anexo código de mi HomePage:

```dart
Future<void> getDeviceInfo() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {

        AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
        Map<String, dynamic> androidData = androidInfo.toMap();
        androidData.forEach((key, value) {
            //se imprime los datos del dispositivo
            print('$key: $value');
        });
    }

    final info = await deviceInfo.deviceInfo;
    //print(info.toMap());
   //print(info.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por temas de seguridad Android o Ios ya no permiten que sea un identidicador unico, antes se usaba el imei o la Mac, pero ya no se puede.

Pero con la libreria device_info_plus que estas usando se puede sacar un id unico, pero que al reinstalar la app va a cambiar pero para ciertos funcionamientos ayuda.

Un ejemplo de uso puede ser asi.

```
 Future<String?> _getId() async {
  var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  if (Platform.isIOS) { // import 'dart:io'
    var iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    return iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor; // unique ID on iOS
  } else if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidDeviceInfo.androidId; // unique ID on Android
  }
}
```

Comment: así es amigo, ya estoy desarrollando mi app basada en el Android Id, tuve que buscar mucha información, pero coincido con tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaciones de Android developer sobre los identificadores únicos.

Revisalo para plantear mejor tu pregunta y saber en que caso practico realmente lo puedes aplicar.

Firebase por ejemplo tiene esta forma:

```
  val uniqueID: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids?hl=es-419

Comment: La pregunta indica Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Usando el plugin [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) , deberías obtener el id único mediante `build.androidId` , ejemplo:

```
Future<void> getDeviceInfo() async {

    String deviceIdentifier = "unknown";
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
       var androidInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
       deviceIdentifier = androidInfo.androidId;
    }

    return deviceIdentifier;
}
```

pero si usas una versión 4.1.0 o posterior de [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus), ya no se podrá obtener `androidId` en el caso de Android.